# Why define linear transformations with two equations when we can use one?

Tags: linear-algebra, linear-transformations

The additivity and scaling requirements for linear transformations can merge into a single equation:
$$T(a\vec x+b\vec y)=aT(\vec x)+bT(\vec y)$$
Setting $a=b=1$ gives additivity and setting $b=0$ gives scaling. Why is this single equation not used as the definition of linear transformations? Is it because additivity and scaling aren't immediately obvious from this definition, or is it because it is harder to determine if a transformation is linear with this definition?

Comment: I think this equation _is_ sometimes used. For the purpose of _learning_ about linear transformations, however, doing things one at a time might work better. And if you assume the reader already knows linear transformations, you might not feel it necessary to show the equation at all.

Comment: Sometimes it is given as the definition. There are pedagogical Advantages for each definition, but it really matters very little which one is used.

Comment: Actually, I have encountered this equation in a slightly different manner, this is to say, we only require $T(ax+y)=aT(x)+T(y)$ which is already sufficient, too.

Comment: Why not $T(a\vec{x} + b) = a T(\vec{x}) + b$? There are many equivalent ways to state this condition, so the choice of which one to present first is more or less arbitrary. If you prefer having a "one line" definition, then you may prefer this one. However, the "additivity and scaling" definitions may be more intuitive for someone seeing it for the first time.

Comment: I think most textbooks will mention both of these. But I second the others who say that this doesn't really matter

Answer (score 2):

If you want you can also use a simpler equation:
$$
T(x+ky)=T(x)+kT(y)
$$
(you  can prove it as  an exercise). But the use of the two step proof, for addition and for scalar multiplication, is more expressive because it is a direct application of the axioms that define a vector space.